# How do I use the WatchDescriptor struct generated by inotify-rs to match events to files that generated them?

Tags: c, rust, inotify, newtype

I'm using Inotify (through the inotify-rs wrapper) to watch a large number of files (not directories) across a filesystem.

The following inotify-rs method returns a `WatchDescriptor` struct:

```rust
add_watch<P>(&mut self, path: P, mask: WatchMask) -> io::Result<WatchDescriptor>
where
   P: AsRef<Path>
```

`WatchDescriptor` is a newtype struct: `pub struct WatchDescriptor(RawFd);` where `std::os::unix::io::RawFd` is type `c_int`/`f32`

the Inotify subsystem returns an `inotify_event` struct each time a watch is triggered:

```c
struct inotify_event {
        int      wd;       /* Watch descriptor */
        uint32_t mask;     /* Mask describing event */
        uint32_t cookie;   /* Unique cookie associating related
                                events (for rename(2)) */
        uint32_t len;      /* Size of name field */
        char     name[];   /* Optional null-terminated name */
    };
```

The "Watch descriptor" `int wd` matches the watch descriptor generated by the initial call to `add_watch()`

In turn, the inotify-rs wrapper returns the following event struct:

```rust
pub struct Event<'a> {    
    pub wd    : WatchDescriptor,
    pub mask  : EventMask,
    pub cookie: u32,
    pub name  : &'a OsStr,
}
```

I am trying to use `Event.wd` to match the event to a file from a list of files being watched. (`.name` only returns a filename if the event triggered on a watch for a directory) I have been unsuccessful at trying to use a `HashMap` because the struct `WatchDescriptor` does not derive the `Hash` trait. I tried to fork the crate and implement that myself, but that opened up an entirely new can of worms.

The simplest way should be to use `Event.wd.0` to get a `c_int`/`i32` but then I have to deal with `error: field '0' of struct 'inotify::WatchDescriptor' is private`

Is there a simple way to do this, short of re-writing the wrapper to behave the way I want it, or to do a PR and wait for it to be merged?

I have considered creating an `Inotify` for each file being watched, but in a scenario where hundreds of files could be watched, this will be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: Given that `Event` has `.name`, can't you use that to map back to the file already?

Comment: loganfsmyth: `.name` only returns a filename if a directory is being watched. Edited question to include that info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some substantial issues with this library:

- The poor choice of type to represent the inotify watch descriptor. Inotify watch descriptors are *not* Unix file descriptors, they are just some integral number, scoped per inotify file descriptor. Not a flaw by itself, but I certainly would view that as a red flag.
- As noted above, inotify watch descriptor values are scoped per parent inotify file descriptor. This makes the use of `[derive(Eq)]` on `WatchDescriptor` highly questionable. Looks like a straight-up bug.
- There is nothing to ensure that inotify watches are closed before closing the inotify descriptor. There is nothing to ensure that watch descriptors don't get reused behind your back (they can be reused after watch descriptor number wraps). Those issues probably won't bite you immediately, but… IMO, the entire inotify-rs should have been declared `unsafe`. It does not add any actual safety on top of inotify, just some sugar and pointless wrappers. It does not even implement `Drop` for the watch descriptor!
- The library does nothing to highlight major gotchas of inotify: event queue overflows, `IN_IGNORED` and hard links sharing the same inode (and the same inotify watch descriptors!)

I recommend you to carefully read the inotify documentation and write your own wrapper if necessary. This library won't save you any trouble.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Yes, it does seem like the library needs some work. I have managed to fork it and make a few changes that solve my use case (for now), but the issues you've highlighted are making me think twice about deploying anything based on this library.

Comment: In defense of `inotify-rs`, many people have been hit by inotify trickiness in the past. Android `FileObserver` has precisely same issues. Java 7 `WatchService` reports inotify queue overflows, but does not properly account for the other issues. And even if the API can handle them transparently, everyone tends to forget about hardlinks…

Comment: gotcha, but I'm evaluating whether it would be better to just poll in my usecase